# Maven cxf-codegen-plugin doesn't follow redirect in xsd:import

Tags: java, maven, soap, xsd, cxf

I have a Maven project where Java code is generated from a WSDL file using org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin 3.5.1

The WSDL imports an XSD schema, which in turn imports a schema from schemas.xmlsoap.org using this directive:

`<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>`

Yesterday this schema was moved temporarily (HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect) to https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

Now the SAX parser fails with org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: premature end of file, apparently because the XSD import doesn't follow the redirect and returns an empty file.

I would gladly change the schemaLocation to https, but since it's only a temporary redirect, I'd rather follow the redirect instead.

Is there a configuration option for Apache CXF to follow redirects? I didn't find any at https://cxf.apache.org/.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @KarthikaiselvanR in a way. The problem solved itself after a few days; the redirect was replaced by a direct response again. Meanwhile, I had worked around it by downloading the schema and using the local schemaLocation with a file: URL. This is more robust anyway, as it avoids external interference on my builds.